# Yii конструктор форм (form builder)

Tags: php, yii

Как через генератор форм в `Yii` задать дефолтное значение(**с атрибутом selected**) в выпадающем списке?

Пробовал так:

```
$form['object']['object_type']->options = array(
            $object->object_type_id => array('selected' => 'selected'
            )
        );
```

и так:

```
$form['object']['object_type']->options = array(
            $object->object_type_id => array('selected' => TRUE
            )
        );
```

UPD: уточнил вопрос
UPD2: хз что сделал, но первый вариант заработал :)

Answer (score 2):

Я делаю так:

Controller

```
$user = User::model()->find('uid = :uid', array("uid"=>$uid));
$profile = new ProfileForm();
foreach($profile->attributes as $name=>$value){
    $profile->$name = $user->$name;
}
```

View

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm("", "post", array("id"=>"profileMainForm", "name"=>"profileMainForm"));?>
    <label>Ваш город</label>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($profile, "city", CHtml::listData(ServiceUser::getCitiesForDropDownList(),'id','text'));?>
    <input type="submit" value="ГОТОВО">
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

Comment: @Demyan112rv я вас ввёл в заблуждение. [Имелся ввиду конструктор форм (form builder)][1]  
Ваш вариант по своему хорош, но мне надо описать довольно большую форму. Для облегчения поддержания и что бы не плодить кучу кода, использую конструктор.
 

  [1]: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/form.builder

Comment: @zenith понятно, с конструктором не работал